# How to store response data as variable in typescript/ angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to typescript. I have got an id generated after post function. Now by using that _id generated in post,using that i must call PUT function for play pause, when play pause button is called response must go to server. I am here by sharing my code of both ts and API service,

API code for PUT:

```
    edit(updateId) {
  console.log(updateId);
  let authToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
  var company_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id'));
  var queries = "?authToken=" + authToken + "&&_id="+ company_id +"&&view_id=2";
 return this.http.put(urlBase + '/timerEntry/' + updateId ,options)
                  .map(this.extractData)
                  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

TS code:
This is for POST function

```
this.ApiService
 .addtimerEntries(new_task)
              .subscribe(
                entry  => {
                 console.log(entry)
                  this.todays.today.push(entry.data[0]);
                  this.updateId = entry.data[0]._id;
                 console.log(this.updateId);
              this.toasterService.pop('success', 'Entry added 
               successfully');
              this.newTask.hide();
            },
          error => {
          this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
        });
```

This is for PUT function:

```
 playTimer() {
     this.timerService.playTimer();
      this.playDiv = true;
      console.log(this.updateId);
      if (this.updateId){ 
    this.ApiService
           .edit( this.updateId)
           .subscribe(
             user => {
               console.log(user);
               this.ApiService
                          .getEntries(this.workEmail)
                          .subscribe(
                            entries  => {
                              console.log(entries);
                              this.entries = entries;
                      this.toasterService.pop('success', 'updated successfully');},
                    error => {
                      //console.log(error);
                    });
             },
             error => {
                this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!');
             });
    }
    }
    pauseTimer() {
     this.timerService.pauseTimer();
      this.playDiv = false;
    }
```

Consoled Output:

```
data:Array(1)
0:Object
category_id:1
client_id:15
company_id:4
department_id:26
entry_type:"checkin_entry"
project_id:7
subcategories:Array(1)
times:Array(1)
workEmail:"test3@test.com"
_id:"59362522325a5a0786f661b3"
```

Comment: from where you are calling `edit function`?

Comment: are you getting `console.log(this.updateId);` as undefined

Comment: no i have got that _id now, when i press play/pause button

Comment: ok, where are you getting the issue now?

Comment: it is showing 404 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146033/discussion-between-sravan-and-tulsi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you called different `baseUrl` for `post` and `put`. so it is giving `404 error`

So, in  `PUT` change

`return this.http.put(urlBase + '/timerEntry/' + updateId ,options)`

to

`return this.http.put(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry/' + updateId ,options)`

So, your service code will be,

```
edit(updateId) { 
    console.log(updateId); 
    let authToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authToken')); 
    var company_id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_id')); 
    var queries = "?authToken=" + authToken + "&&_id="+ company_id +"&&view_id=2"; 
    return this.http.put(timerUrlBase + '/timerEntry/' + updateId ,options) 
    .map(this.extractData) 
    .catch(this.handleError); 
}
```